# Windows Phone 8 App, navigate to store

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i have a windows phone 8 app, where there are 2 versions an light and a full version. i would like to ask the user if the likes the app and direct him to the store page for my full version of the app.

I have tryed the following

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=3e1603cd-56a3-49aa-8d0c-cf4bee8cefd2", UriKind.Absolute));
```

But it throws an null error, how can navigate my user to the store page of my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use WebBrowserTask:

```
 WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
 webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=3e1603cd-56a3-49aa-8d0c-cf4bee8cefd2");
 webBrowserTask.Show();
```

I assume (because it's different App) that you don't want to use:

```
 MarketplaceDetailTask _marketPlaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
 _marketPlaceDetailTask.Show();
```